# Issue w/ C# application getting stuck in sigsuspend()

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono

I'm using mono 5.4 to run multithreaded C# code with mono-service.exe on Centos 6.8.

I have the following issue:

- It starts with a sudden increase in CPU usage and thread count (thread count increases slower than CPU but the onset point is the same - same time);
- there is an increase in CLOSE_WAIT sockets - they never close while CPU is pegged;
- If close() syscall is issued w/ gdb then the execution returns back to normal;

When checking the thread information w/ gdb this is what I see:

```
  181 Thread 0x7f42fa3e0700 (LWP 13122)  0x00007f435b14d844 in do_sigsuspend (set=<value optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigsuspend.c:63
  180 Thread 0x7f42fa1df700 (LWP 14121)  0x00007f435b14d844 in do_sigsuspend (set=<value optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigsuspend.c:63
  179 Thread 0x7f42f9fde700 (LWP 15218)  0x00007f435b14d844 in do_sigsuspend (set=<value optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigsuspend.c:63
  178 Thread 0x7f42f9ddd700 (LWP 16282)  0x00007f435b14d844 in do_sigsuspend (set=<value optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigsuspend.c:63
  177 Thread 0x7f42f9bdc700 (LWP 17308)  0x00007f435b14d844 in do_sigsuspend (set=<value optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigsuspend.c:63
  176 Thread 0x7f42f99db700 (LWP 18379)  0x00007f435b14d844 in do_sigsuspend (set=<value optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigsuspend.c:63
```

**Question**: under what circumstances is sigsuspend() ussually called and how can it related to CLOSE_WAIT socket leak?